# Cache Coherency updation in SMP

Tags: multithreading, architecture, operating-system, multiprocessing

Taking a SMP (Symmetric Multi-processing) machine which has two seprate processors in it.

Here if two threads are running on two different processors and sharing some data.

This Shared data is kept into two different processor's cache for the two running threads.

So ,if thread 1 (running in furst processor) updates the value of the shared data in its cache ,then the thread running on the second processor will not be able to get the updated data ?

Is this problem correct ? 
How this problem is solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved with cache coherency hardware.

Modern multi-core processors use sophisticated cache coherency protocols. While understanding the intricacies of these protocols is probably not useful, understanding the basic concepts behind them is extremely valuable.  Understanding the [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) is a great starting point.

Generally, before a processor can perform a cached write to a chunk of cacheable memory, its cache must hold that memory exclusively. That is, no other processors may cache it.

So if the first processor goes to write to an area of memory, it will acquire that memory exclusively in its cache using the inter-cache protocol. If the second processor then tries to read that area of memory, it will not find it in its cache, and use the inter-cache protocol to share the latest version with the first processor.

If the second processor wants to write to that area of memory, it will use the inter-cache protocol to invalidate the other processor's cached copy. That will force the first processor to re-acquire the (possibly modified) version before it can read it.

The actual details can vary depending on the hardware specifics. No modern multi-core CPU requires writing data back to main memory to make it visible to other cores.

Comment: Can i say "Cache Coherent Interconnect" in case of ARM is an example ?